# updating score variable from a different class

Tags: xcode, swift, variables, updating

I'm trying to get my score to carry over to a new scene after the game is over and when this happens the score is coming out at 0. The score is set to 0 in my PlayScene as a default but I need it to read what the score is in ScoreScene when the PlayScene is over. Help Please!!

```
import SpriteKit

import AVFoundation

class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

     let scoreText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "System-Bold")
     var score = 0

     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

             self.scoreText.text = "0"
             self.scoreText.fontSize = 42
             self.scoreText.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),          CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) / 1.075)


 func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact) {

    var scene = ScoreScene(size: self.size)
    let skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    skView.presentScene(scene)

 func blockRunner() {

           for(block, blockStatus) in self.blockStatuses {
           var thisBlock = self.childNodeWithName(block)
           if blockStatus.shouldRunBlock() {
            blockStatus.timeGapForNextRun = random()
            blockStatus.currentInterval = 0
            blockStatus.isRunning = true
        }

        if blockStatus.isRunning {
            if thisBlock!.position.x > blockMaxX {
                thisBlock!.position.x -= CGFloat(self.groundSpeed)

            }else {
                thisBlock!.position.x = self.origBlockPositionX
                blockStatus.isRunning = false
                self.score++
                if ((self.score % 10) == 0) {
                    self.groundSpeed++
                }
                self.scoreText.text = String(self.score)

            }
        }else {
            blockStatus.currentInterval++
        }
    }
}
```

and Now when the game is over it switches to Score scene which is below

```
     class ScoreScene: SKScene {
       var playScene = PlayScene()
       let scoreText = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "System-Bold")

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

       self.scoreText.text = "score: \(playScene.score)"
       self.scoreText.fontSize = 42
       self.scoreText.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) / 1.075)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate model to hold your data so you can access it from different parts of the app, I normally use a singleton approach so I can create the class only once and access its values anytime I need. What I would do:

- create a new class player that keep the details about the player like
- score make this class a singleton use this class to populate the
- score value through all the scenes of the game

More details about design patterns in swift [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1) (including singleton)

You will find a lot of code demos for singleton in [here](https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton)